# Sequelize returning one result when counting AVG in Eager Loading

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, eager-loading

I have been trying to fix this problem for a day now but no luck. I am using Sequelize With Nodejs and MySQL dialect.

I am querying for Influencers whilst also calculating their average ratings from a InfluencerRating record. They are associated through a oneToMany relation.

Here is my Influencer modal:

```js
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('influencer', {
    id: {
      autoIncrement: true,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    display_name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      allowNull: false
    },
    link_facebook: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      allowNull: true
    },
    link_soundcloud: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      allowNull: true
    },
    link_twitter: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      allowNull: true
    },
    link_bandcamp: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      allowNull: true
    },
    link_spotify: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      allowNull: true
    },
    link_instagram: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      allowNull: true
    },
    link_deezer: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      allowNull: true
    },
    link_youtube: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      allowNull: true
    },
    link_website: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      allowNull: true
    },
    description_english: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      allowNull: true
    },
    description_french: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      allowNull: true
    },
    information_english: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      allowNull: true
    },
    information_french: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      allowNull: true
    },
    enabled: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: 0
    },
    profile_image: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      allowNull: true
    },
    banner_image: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      allowNull: true
    },
    admin_public_status: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: 1
    }
  }, {
    sequelize,
    tableName: 'influencer',
    timestamps: false,
    underscored: true,
    indexes: [
      {
        name: "PRIMARY",
        unique: true,
        using: "BTREE",
        fields: [
          { name: "id" },
        ]
      },
    ]
  });
};
```

Here is my InfluencerRating modal:

```js
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('influencer_rating', {
    id: {
      autoIncrement: true,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    description: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      allowNull: false
    },
    influencer_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: 'influencer',
        key: 'id'
      }
    },
    rating: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false
    }
  }, {
    sequelize,
    tableName: 'influencer_rating',
    timestamps: false,
    underscored: true,
    indexes: [
      {
        name: "PRIMARY",
        unique: true,
        using: "BTREE",
        fields: [
          { name: "id" },
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "type_id",
        using: "BTREE",
        fields: [
          { name: "influencer_id" },
        ]
      },
    ]
  });
};
```

And here is my associations between them both:

```js
influencer_rating.belongsTo(influencer, { as: "influencer", foreignKey: "influencer_id"});
influencer.hasMany(influencer_rating, { as: "influencer_ratings", foreignKey: "influencer_id"});
```

Here is my query to find influencers and calculate their average ratings:

```js
var influencers = await Influencer.findAll(
        {
            where: {
                [db.Op.and]: [
                    {
                        enabled: true
                    },
                    {
                        display_name: {
                            [db.Op.like]: '%' + filter + '%'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        admin_public_status: true
                    }
                ],
            },
            include: [
              [
                {
                    model: InfluencerRating,
                    as: "influencer_ratings",
                    required: false,
                    attributes: [[Sequelize.fn('AVG', Sequelize.col('rating')), 'rating']]
                }
            ],
            limit: 10,
            offset: 0,
            group: ['id']
        }
    );
```

The query should be returning 2 influencer Objects, but I am only getting one.

I get the wanted behaviour if I delete my :

```js
attributes: [[Sequelize.fn('AVG', Sequelize.col('rating')), 'rating']]
```

I have tried calculating my average outside of my InfluencerRating include but not luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made some changes to findAll. Can give it a try:

```js
var influencers = await Influencer.findAll({
  // whenever hasMany used in include, the main query gets converted to subquery 
  // if limit + offset is applied
  subQuery: false, // <----- instructs not to make a sub query 
  attributes: {
    include: [
      [Sequelize.fn('AVG', Sequelize.col('influencer_ratings.rating')), 'total_rating']
    ],
  },
  where: {
    [db.Op.and]: [
      { enabled: true },
      { display_name: { [db.Op.like]: '%' + filter + '%' } },
      { admin_public_status: true }
    ],
  },
  include: [ // removed extra nesting of array
    {
      model: InfluencerRating,
      as: "influencer_ratings",
      required: false,
      attributes: [],
    }
  ],
  limit: 10,
  offset: 0,
  group: [
    'id',
    // 'influencer_ratings.influencer_id', // add if sql error occurs
  ],
  order: [ // if needed
    [Sequelize.literal('total_rating'), 'DESC'],
  ]
});
```

Few reference links:

- Disable sub query generation(done by sequelize) when hasMany/belongsToMany relation included - https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/1756#issuecomment-54748245
- Using SQL sub queries with ordering: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/sub-queries.html

Alternate approach:

```js
var influencers = await Influencer.findAll({
  attributes: {
    include: [
      [Sequelize.literal(`(
        SELECT
            AVG("influencer_ratings"."rating") AS "avg_rating"
        FROM
            "influencer" AS "influencer1"
            LEFT OUTER JOIN (
                "influencer_ratings" AS "influencer_ratings"
            ) ON "influencer1"."id" = "influencer_ratings"."influencer_id"
        WHERE
            "influencer1"."id" = "influencer"."id"
        GROUP BY
            "influencer1"."id"
    )`), 'avg_rating'], // now this is just a subquery and will not interfere  with other includes
    ],
  },
  where: {
    [db.Op.and]: [
      { enabled: true },
      { display_name: { [db.Op.like]: '%' + filter + '%' } },
      { admin_public_status: true }
    ],
  },
  include: [ // removed extra nesting of array
    // influencer_ratings include not needed now
    // add other includes as needed
  ],
  limit: 10,
  offset: 0,
  order: [ // if needed
    [Sequelize.literal('avg_rating'), 'DESC'],
  ]
});
```

Comment: Removing the extra nesting of array and calling AVG outside of include, but inside attributes instead has solved my problem! Thank you.

Still not quite sure how subQuery works, will look into it!

Comment: Worked for me also by calling AVG outside of include and removing "Sequelize.literal" in the order attribute .
Thank you!